# Logout doesn't work with Laravel JWT-auth

Tags: php, laravel, logout, jwt

I'm using JWT-auth with Laravel Framework to authenticate a user. Laravel is used as server-end framework and the fore-end code is in the framework which is developed by our own. So we use api not web to realize authentication. Login works well in this environment, whereas logout and refresh token can't perform as I wish. I configure everything as [JWT-auth documentation](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/) says.

route.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'api', 'prefix' => 'user', 'namespace' => 'User'], function () {
   Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@login'); // login
   Route::post('/logout', 'AuthController@logout'); // logout (invalidate token)
   Route::post('/refresh', 'AuthController@refresh'); // refresh token});
```

kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'password',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    /*'users' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'user',
    ],*/
],
```

User\AuthController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use AjaxResponse;
use Log;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
    }

    /**
     * login
     * @param Request $request 
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('phone', 'password');

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return AjaxResponse::fail(4001);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    /**
     * logout（invalidate token）
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        Log::debug('yyyyyyyyy');
        auth()->logout();

        return AjaxResponse::succeed(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * refresh token
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * get token structure
     * @param $token
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        if (Auth::user()['deleted_at'] || ! Auth::user()['is_active'])
            return AjaxResponse::fail(4001);
        else
            return AjaxResponse::succeed([
                'access_token' => $token,
                'token_type' => 'bearer',
                'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
                'user_name' => Auth::user()['name'],
                'user_admin' => (bool)Auth::user()['is_admin']
            ]);
    }
}
```

[image: Here posts my response to access logout.]

'yyyyyyyyy' can't be logged. So it seems that the `logout` function in `AuthController` wasn't called.

Is there anything wrong I've written or missed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the message log `yyyyyyyyy` working? is the message `'Successfully logged out'`'s returning? Or it simply, the token that are not invalided?

Comment: @cbaconnier I've updated my question just now. Please recheck it.

Comment: Your screenshot is the results of your `POST` when you hit `/logout` is that right? In that case, the request you do may be wrong. Since you're using the API, it should be `Content-Type: application/json` and the header should contain `Authorization: Bearer <token>`

Comment: In addition of what I explained: _the request you do may be wrong._ I'm guessing this since I'm seeing an HTML screenshot. Laravel's generally redirects you to `/login` _(not `/api/login`)_ because it doesn't see the request as `json` and doesn't see you authenticated.

Comment: @cbaconnier I've found a way to make it work, nonetheless, I don't explain the logic clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few tryings, I've changed the AuthController's constructor and it worked.

User\AuthController

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'refresh', 'logout']]);
}
```

I've added functions as value of 'except', in which I expected to invalidate the present session.